# Method to integrate Touch ID in iOS apps

Tags: ios, security, authentication, ios8, fingerprint

With the recent announcement of Touch ID APIs for third party apps, I am wondering how can we leverage this feature to perform secure transaction ?
I am looking for a method to use Touch ID in my payment application.
One option is to store the password in the keychain and add access policies to invoke Touch ID during payment but the problem is if the device password is compromised, user can roll back to device password to access password stored in keychain.
Does anyone know a better mechanism to manage password & make the transaction smoother & secure using Touch ID ?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the password entry part. In LAContext.h:

```
/// Fallback button title.
/// @discussion Allows fallback button title customization. A default title "Enter Password" is used when
///             this property is left nil. If set to empty string, the button will be hidden.
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *localizedFallbackTitle;
```

Comment: localizedFallbackTitle can be used only if you are launching TouchID UI by using LocalAuthentication APIs but my problem is if I store the password in keychain with access policies, OS itself will prompt for TouchID & it cannot be customised.